# Using @types in WebStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

I'm following the [webpack intro](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) for Angular 2. I'm using WebStorm but when I run `npm start`, an alias for `webpack-dev-server`, I get over 60 TypeScript transpile errors of the following form

```
ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@angular\common\src\directives\ng_class.d.ts:48:34
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in [at-loader] node_modules\@angular\common\src\pipes\async_pipe.d.ts:44:38
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

I remember having similar issues when using typings, and resolved that by adding `///<reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>` to the top of a `ts` file at the root of my application.

However, this webpack sample uses the new `@types` but I can't seem to get it to play nice with WebStorm. I've tried updating `tsconfig.json` with the  `typeRoots` attribute as suggested [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9725), but to no avail. You can find the source for this webpack demo [here](https://github.com/jdbriaris/angular-webpack).

Any ideas how to get this working in WebStorm?

Comment: Get same problems in VSCode. However, for both VSCode and WebStorm the server is running and working. How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: looks like it does not recognize the ES6 features = your babel is not configured properly

Comment: @smnbbrv Not sure I understand. Why do I have to configure my babel? This example is straight from the angular website. Should it not work?

Answer (score 1):

@james-b

Change your TS rule in *webpack.common.js* to *loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']* like shown below:

**Your webpack.common.js code:**

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: [{
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                options: { configFileName: helpers.root('tsconfig.json') }
            } , 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
    ]
},
```

**Updated webpack.common.js code:**

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        }
    ]
},
```